# Close ajax accordion with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ajax accordion on that I want to close after 5 seconds from the page loading.  I'm trying to do this with javascript but having no luck.  I'm trying to change the accordion control of SelectedIndex to a value that will collapse the accordion.  SelectedIndex = 0 is open (default), and I'm trying to change it to 1 after the javascript timer runs out.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// close the accordion after 5 seconds
setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById('MainContent_Accordion1').SelectedIndex = 1; }, 5000); });
```

I'm not getting any errors on the java from the console, but the accordion isn't closing.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you want to collapse the currently visible section or remove the accordion from the page? Is it jQuery UI Accordion that you use?

Comment: Is it SelectedIndex that is 0 by default, or selectedIndex? One capital letter where it shouldn't be will cause a headache.

Comment: I don't know the tool being used at all but seems highly improbable the DOM gets manipulated without using an API method for the widget after it has already been initialized

Comment: Streamside, I'm trying to collapse the accordion, not hide it.  Changing the SelectedIndex will do that.  I'm using the AjaxControlToolbox Accordion control.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found something that works.

```
setTimeout(function () {
            var behavior = $get("<%Accordion1.ClientID%>").AccordionBehavior;
            behavior.set_SelectedIndex(1);}, 5000);
```

This solution does what I wanted, in that it behaves just as if the user clicked the accordion button.  The other solutions I found basically would do an instantaneous hide and not animate the collapse of the accordion.  By setting the index to a value higher than the maximum number, it in effect collapses the accordion.  In my case I only have one pane, so setting the index from 0 to 1 will do the trick.

Comment: Did you try behavior.set_SelectedIndex(-1); ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `Accordion` panel's `SelectedIndex` property doesn't state that the Accordion panel is open or close. It indicates which pane out of many is currently displayed. So, it could be `0, 1, 2 ... n` (where n indicates number of panes - 1).

The definition for the `SelectedIndex` property from [Ajax Control Toolkit website](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/Accordion/Accordion.aspx) is as follows

`SelectedIndex` - The AccordionPane to be initially visible

And, this value is stored in a hidden field with the name containing "*_AccordionExtender_ClientState*".

**TIP**

Ok, back to solving your issue. First of all you need to think in HTML rather than server side properties of the Accordion control because you are going to manipulate it in client side using `JavaScript`. `Accordion` control is translated to a bunch of `DIV` elements in client side with `CSS` class names like `accordionHeader` and `accordionHeaderSelected` (this could vary depending on whether you've assigned custom classes during design time). See these images and focus on the highlighted areas.

**When the pane is expanded**
[image]

When a pane is expanded it's DIV contains `class = "accordionHeaderSelected"`. And, the hidden filed's value is the index of the pane selected (in this case first pane, i.e. 0). Also note the style property of the selected pane's content DIV.

**When the pane is collapsed**
[image]

When a pane is collapsed it's DIV contains `class = "accordionHeader"`. And, the hidden filed's value is always -1. Also note the style property of the selected pane's content DIV.

Therefore, in your `JavaScript` make use of these values to identify the currently expanded DIV. Then do follow these steps.

1. change the element class to  `class = "accordionHeader"`
2. Find the content DIV related to the selected pane and close it by setting following style of the content DIV.

   style = 'height: 0px; overflow: hidden; display: none; opacity: 0;'
3. You should also make the hidden field value = -1

Hope this make sense to you. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Sam, thanks for the response.  Very thorough.  I managed to find a solution that works for me, see below.  I changed the SelectedIndex to a value higher than the maximum number of panes.  This in effect collapses the current accordion.

Comment: Oh that's completely new to me. :D Thanks for sharing.